# I want to rename colnames for 4 data frames using a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

So each data frame has the same colnames and I need to use a for loop to change the colnames at one time.

```
RD1df=read.table(RD1url,skip=33)
RD2df=read.table(RD2url,skip=33)
RD3df=read.table(RD3url,skip=33)
RD4df=read.table(RD4url,skip=33)

Sites=list(RD1df,RD2df,RD3df,RD4df)
for(colnames in Sites) 
{colnames=c("Agency", "SiteId", 
"DateTime", "Measure", 
"DataValue")}'''
```

This is the code I've tried running, and there is no error message that pops up from the for loop but the colnames don't change

Comment: Are the dataframes in a list or in the global environment?

Comment: @TarJae so I have the as read.table that I used a paste0 to create because they're all similar URLs, and then I put them into that list  called Sites

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NewNames <- function(x) {
  names(x)<- c("Agency", "SiteId", "DateTime", "Measure", "DataValue")
  return(x)
}

Sites <- lapply(Sites, NewNames)
```

or as a for loop:

```
for (i in seq_along(Sites)) {
  names(Sites[[i]]) <- c("Agency", "SiteId", "DateTime", "Measure", "DataValue")
}
```

Comment: since I need to use a for loop, can I substitute the apply for a for loop? It looks like I may want to keep the top part to start the for loop tho? and in that for loop I would want it to look like: for (x in sites) {...

Comment: `for (i in seq_along(Sites)) {
  names(Sites[[i]]) <- c("Agency", "SiteId", "DateTime", "Measure", "DataValue")
}`